# Times Matrix dimensions must agree in matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, communication

I am required to record an audio signal then convert it to the spectrum form then filter it.

this how I'm recording my signal & convert it to spectrum:

```
        % Record your voice for 10 seconds.
recObj = audiorecorder;
disp('Start speaking.')
recordblocking(recObj,10);
disp('End of Recording.');

% Play back the recording.
play(recObj);

% Store data in double-precision array.
myRecording = getaudiodata(recObj);
% Plot the waveform.
figure
plot(myRecording);
fs = 48000;
% get the spectrum.
x=myRecording;
xf=fftshift(fft(x)*(1/fs));
figure
plot(real(xf));
```

Now I want to filter any spectrum greater than 4k
I used a zeroes & ones of Ideal Filtering 
 But It always give me (times
Matrix dimensions must agree). And I don't know how to solve it !

```
% Here is my Ideal filter
n1=-80000:-4000;
n2=-4000:4000;
n3=4000:80000;
n=[n1 n2 n3];

x1=zeros(1,length(n1));
x2=ones(1,length(n2));
x3=zeros(1,length(n3));
x=[x1 x2 x3];

y=x.*xf;
figure
plot(n,y);
```

Comment: At what line do you get this error?

Comment: @dfri when I use this line to filter  :
y=x.*xf;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that your xf vector has 80000 elements, while n1+n2+n3=160003.

Try replacing

```
n1=-80000:-4000;
n2=-4000:4000;
n3=4000:80000;
n=[n1 n2 n3];
```

with

```
n1=-39999:-4001;
n2=-4000:4000;
n3=4001:40000;
n=[n1 n2 n3];
```

and

```
x=[x1 x2 x3];
```

with

```
x=[x1 x2 x3]';
```

(you have to transpose the x vector). Hope it works well for you.